# MNIST and SVHN resize

Tags: mnist

all.

I want to use MNIST and SVHN dataset.

MNIST is 28x28 and SVHN is 32x32.

so I want to make those dataset have same size.

But I`m not sure which one is the better.

```
1.Resize MNIST 28x28 to 32x32 
2.Resize SVHN 32x32 to 28x28
```

Comment: Do you mean zero padding the MNIST images for example? I would zero-pad the MNIST images, but in general I would recommend just working on one of them, because MNIST is quite artificial. MNIST is good if you want to test a generic learning algorithm for example.

Answer (score 2):

Choose the second one(resize MNIST, or add zero padding for MNIST).

There is only one reason, when we will crop or resize from SVHN to MNIST we will lose some data anyway.

But SVHN and MNIST have not the only different size of pictures, but the number of channels(SVHN is colored and probably is in RGB). The question here is "Should we change RGB to Grayscale or vice versa?"

And my answer for it is "it depends". Depends on the goals of the final application of NN. What color mode will have pictures from the general sample? Would it be other MNIST pictures or colored handwritten digits or maybe general digits in our life?

That answer you have to answer yourself.